# Insert country code to phone input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a "contact us" form, I need to insert a country code (ie 972, 1, 91) to the phone input field after choosing the country from the select list. 
For example;
If a user chooses "US" from the list, than the phone input field will start with the number "1" and than the user will continue to write his number. How do I do that with jQuery?

Thank you

Comment: codepen.io/anon/pen/YPKLoX - but I dont know how to insert the outcome to a specefic input field. Ho to tell hime "show the number in XXX input filed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this buy adding the value as code of the Country like for `US` the value of option should be `1`

Your **HTML** should be,

```
<select id="country">
   <option value="">Select Country</option>
   <option value="1">US</select>
   <option value="91">IN</select>
</select><br/>
Code: <input type="text" id="code" />
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
   $('#country').on('change',function(){
       $('#code').val(this.value);// changing the code textbox value by current country value
   });
});
```

Comment: intesting. gonna try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="1">US</option>
    <option value="+44 ">UK</option>
</select>
<input id="phone" type="text" name="phone">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#country').on('change', function() {
        $('#phone').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="country">
   <option value="">Select Country</option>
   <option value="1">US</option>
   <option value="91">IN</option>
   </select>
<br><br>
Code: <input type="text" id="code" />

$(function() {
    $('#country').on('change', function() {
        $('#phone').val($(this).val());
    });
});`enter code here`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).